# jquery conflicting with another lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using various jQuery libaries for a site from 2 plugins, but they are conflicting, I dont have the greatest knowledge of jQuery so an idiots guide might be helpful tbh.

the "jQuery-loader" is interering with the "jQuery.min.js" (one of the two plugin's work without the other)

What can I do to resolve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.smartmenus.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
        subMenusSubOffsetX: 1,
        subMenusSubOffsetY: -8
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is `libs/jquery-loader.js`. Perhaps it's loading the jquery library so you don't need to load jquery separately?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I think you have multiple jquery libraries..if so remove it..

Comment: the libs/jquery-loader.js appears to be loading another library, I've tried using only one library but then only the corresponding plugin works, the other is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include JQuery at the top of all other scripts that require Jquery. Try moving the below code to the top:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've just tried this, it has enabled one of the plugins but disabled the other.

Comment: Can you provide links to the `js/js.js` and `libs/jquery-loader.js` source code?

Comment: http://designandintention.com/Raikon1.2/js/js.js
http://designandintention.com/Raikon1.2/libs/jquery-loader.js

Comment: Move your `js/js.js` script to be the last included of all scripts. Does this help?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. I've updated it on the live page. I dont know enough about jQuery to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery.noConflict(). It will solves your problem. read more [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/][1]. Find Below example,

```
   jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
        subMenusSubOffsetX: 1,
        subMenusSubOffsetY: -8
    });
   });
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would I apply this to the jQuery in the Google library eg <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>